# generate multiple plots by querying mongodb using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I would like to speed up a plotting function that looks up data from mongodb atlas. I used examples from online, however I'm not sure if it is the correct implementation. Using `multiprocessing.Pool()` seems slower than doing it without the package. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[image: jupyter notebook output]

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from matplotlib.backends.backend_svg import FigureCanvasSVG
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import io
import multiprocessing
import time

lstOfwavelengths = list(range(220,810,10))

def build_graph_mongo_multiproc(pltcodeWithSuffix,wellID):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.databasename
    img = io.BytesIO()
    fig = Figure(figsize=(0.6,0.6))
    axis = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    absvals = db[pltcodeWithSuffix].find({"Wavelength":wavelength})
    absvals = {k:v for k,v in absvals[0].items() if k}
    axis.plot(lstOfwavelengths,absvals)
    axis.set_title(f'{pltcodeWithSuffix}:{wellID}',fontsize=9)
    axis.title.set_position([.5, .6])
    axis.tick_params(
            which='both',
            bottom=False,
            left=False,
            labelbottom=False,
            labelleft=False)
    FigureCanvasSVG(fig).print_svg(img)
    lstOfPlts.append(img.getvalue() )
```

The only difference from the single and multiproc function is that the MongoClient is called once, outside the function.

Comment: What happens if each process executes `client = MongoClient()`?

Comment: its required for mongodb atlas, if you want to run multiprocessing

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood that part. Could it be something related to this call `lstOfPlts.append(img.getvalue() )`? What happens if, for the sake of trying, you comment it out? What time do you get?

Comment: No worries, it still takes about ~30 secs to complete the task with that line commented; but if I comment that I won't have the list of figures that I need to plot

Comment: Alright, I am a bit lost here. My understanding is that one of the instructions is actually raising a lock, which prevents the processes to run at the same time and basically make them wait for each other. Another thing is that I would advise to explicitly pass as an argument of the function each variable that is used inside the function but declared outside of its scope. This may not do much, but hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: Have a look at this doc (https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#multi-threading), this sounds like the lock I just mentioned. What happens if you comment `img = io.BytesIO()`, `FigureCanvasSVG(fig).print_svg(img)` and `lstOfPlts.append(img.getvalue() )` ?

Comment: Yeah, i think you are right about the lock, that would explain the long processing time. I found an article that helped me out. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this great article: [The efficient way of using multiprocessing with pymongo](https://medium.com/@saksham.malhotra2196/the-efficient-way-of-using-multiprocessing-with-pymongo-a7f1cf72b5b7)

Using the article as a template, I was able to reduce the computation time to ~7.5 seconds instead of 21 seconds. I'm sure someone more experienced can shave off more time, but I think that is suffice for my level.

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
lstOfPlots = manager.list()

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def getAllWellVals(db,pltcodeWithSuffix,wellID):
    lstOfVals = []
    for i in db[pltcodeWithSuffix].find({}, {wellID:1,'_id':0}):
        lstOfVals.append(i[wellID])
    return lstOfVals

def build_graph_mongo_multiproc(chunk,pltcodeWithSuffix):
    global lstOfPlots
    client=MongoClient(connect_string,maxPoolSize=10000)
    db = client[dbname]
    #loop over the id's in the chunk and do the plotting with each
    for wid in chunk:
        #do the plotting with document collection.find_one(id)
        img = io.BytesIO()
        fig = Figure(figsize=(0.6,0.6))
        axis = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        absVals = getAllWellVals(db,pltcodeWithSuffix,wid)
        axis.plot(lstOfwavelengths,absVals)
        axis.set_title(f'{wid}',fontsize=9)
        axis.title.set_position([.5, .6])
        axis.tick_params(
                which='both',
                bottom=False,
                left=False,
                labelbottom=False,
                labelleft=False)
        FigureCanvasSVG(fig).print_svg(img)
        result = img.getvalue()
        lstOfPlots.append(result)
```